# How to prove a rule when a ration is periodic either not?

Tags: arithmetic, decimal-expansion

My son asked me, why division of integers sometimes produces periodic and sometimes decimal real numbers.

What has come so far to my mind, is that while we use a decimal system, then every non-periodic real value can be represented as something divided by 10, and 10 is a product of 2 and 5.

Maybe there is a known rule/theorem/proof, something like "if ... applies to `a/b`, then it can't be a periodic value"?

Comment: If I don't remenber wrongly the fraction $\frac ab$ is "decimal" (non periodic) if and only if the denominator $b$ is of the form $2^n\cdot 5^m$.

Comment: but why? and how to formalize

Comment: Look at my HINT below.

Answer (score 1):

HINT.-WLOG we consider the integer part equal to $0$. You have only three possibilities:
$$\begin{cases}1)\space 0.a_1a_2.....a_n\\2)\space 0.\overline{a_1a_2.....a_n}\\3)\space 0.a_1a_2.....a_n\overline{b_1b_2.....b_m}\end{cases}$$ where the overline means periodicity. We make the proof just with concrete examples (you can generalize to any example follow the same procedure)
$$\begin{cases}1)\space 0.37=\dfrac{37}{100}=\dfrac{37}{2^2\cdot5^2}\\2)\space0.\overline{37}=\dfrac{37}{100}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{100}+\dfrac{1}{100^2}+\cdots\right)\\3)\space0.5\overline{37}=0.5+0.\overline{37}\end{cases}  $$
You can operate in $2)$ finding $\dfrac{37}{99}$ then verify that fractions having as denominator $9$,$99$,$999$,.....,are periodic also. Similarly with $3)$.

Thus the comment above.